# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when trying to call an object from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I am trying to write an implementation of Chess for a school assignment but i have ran into an issue i cant seem to fix.

```
def askpiece(self,player):
    inputstring=input(player.name+ ", what is the location of the piece you would like to move (e.g.)? ")
    x,y=inputstring
    y=int(y)
    if (x,y) in self and self[(x,y)].name[1] == player.tag:
        if self[(x,y)].canmove(self,player):
            return (x,y)
        else:
            print("the selected piece currently can't move, try again.")
    elif self[(x,y)].name[1] != player.tag:
        print("the piece you are trying to move belongs to the other player, try again.")
        self.askpiece(player)
    elif (x,y) not in self:
        print("there is currently no piece on the specified location, try again.")

def canmove(self,board,player):  #controls if the piece can move in atleast one way 

                                 #included the function canmove too in case that is what is causing the error
    lettertonumber={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
    numbertoletter={1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:"d"}
    for move in self.canmove:
        if lettertonumber[self.x]+move[0] in [1,4] and self.y+move[1] in [1,5]:
            if (lettertonumber[self.x]+move[0],self.y+move[1]) in board:
                if self.name[1] != player.tag:
                    return True
            else:
                return True
    return False
```

when i call on this function the function correctly asks me the location of the piece i'd like to move (for example the rook on b1), checks if that piece exists and if that piece actually belongs to me, but then generates a TypeError:

```
File "Schaak.py", line 31, in <module>
   game()
File "Schaak.py", line 27, in game
   (x,y)=askpiece(bord,player)
File "Schaak.py", line 9, in askpiece
   if board[(x,y)].canmove(board,player) == True:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

in askpiece, self is a dictionary called "board" and self[(x,y)] is a chesspiece in the dictionary, when i ask the code to print self[(x,y)] it correctly states that the object is "class: Rook" and if i ask it to print the object itself the output is correct too. no matter how i change the syntax i seem to get this error (unless i change it to something that generates a different error) and in the rest of the code i dont get any errors when i call on self[(x,y)]

Comment: I am not able to find line `if board[(x,y)].canmove(board,player) == True:` in your code.

Comment: have you reused the name `canmove` anywhere in your code and assigned it to some list?

Comment: yup! that's it! I can't believe i overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `canmove()`

```
for move in self.canmove:
```

implies you set this attribute to a list at some point. Methods and instance variables exist in the same namespace (indeed, a method is nothing more than a [class] variable that happens to be callable), so you cannot reuse the same name. One name or the other will have to change; since the list variable seems more likely to only be used internally, I'd suggest changing it to `_canmove`, unless there is a more appropriate name to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed the name of the method to can_move and it fixed the whole thing!

Comment: Even better! That makes the method name conform better to PEP8.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code `canmove` has been assigned to a `list` so when you try `canmove(board,player)` you get the error:

```
In [26]: canmove = []

In [27]: canmove = []

In [28]: canmove()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2a6706ff3740> in <module>()
----> 1 canmove()

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a simple underscore in the name of the function fixed the whole thing!